# Чем лучше сверстать такие элементы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как лучше разместить иконку и кнопку в форме? label или просто абсолютным позиционированием?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тег `label` служит для описания поля. У вас эту роль уже плейсхолдеры выполняют.

Так как иконка - это стилизация в данном случае, то можно сделать абсолютный `::before` с иконкой на фоне, и не делать никакие элементы.

Кнопку нужно делать кнопкой. Тег `button` с маргином типа `30px auto -30px` (отрицательный снизу для съедания места под кнопкой) и бордером_или_тенью под цвет фона.